# Sinumerik error “Warning MBDDE didn’t post initcomplete …

Tags: g-code

When starting up my 1994 geiss 5 axis cnc I keep getting the error “warning application “mbdde” didn’t post initcomplete! Press enter to continue . Can anyone elaborate what this alarm means and how I can fix it ? Thanks

I have tried hard reset and nck warm resets . Beyond that I have no idea how to address this . Please help